# Set state based on value of array item in previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am new to programming and I am trying to make a function in React that adds a team to an array of selected teams but only if there are less than 2 teams selected and if the team is available (not already chosen). It is working to limit the array to only 2 values but the array will accept the same team twice and I am not sure why. For example if the user clicks ATL twice then that team will be in the array twice. What did I do wrong here and what should I change in order to fix it? Sorry if the question is too simple for this forum, I am new.

Here is the code where I am changing the state and checking if gameState.selected_teams[0] != team:

```js
function App() {

  const [gameState, setGameState] = useState({
    cards: Cards,
    selected_teams: []
  });

  function setTeam(team){
    if (gameState.selected_teams.length < 2 && gameState.selected_teams[0] != team) {
      setGameState((prevState) => ({
        cards: prevState.cards,
        selected_teams: [
          ...prevState.selected_teams, {
            team
          }
        ]
      }))
    } 
  }
```

And for the component that calls the setTeam function:

```js
function TeamSelect({cards, setTeam}) {
    var teams = Object.keys(cards);
    return (
        <div className='flex-container'>
            <div className='team-container'>
                {
                    teams.map(team => (
                        <div 
                        onClick={() => setTeam(team)}
                        className='team-label' key={team}>
                            {team}
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding an object `{team: team}` to your selected teams array each time you perform your click here:

```js
selected_teams: [
  ...prevState.selected_teams, {
    team
  }
]
```

but your `team` key that you pass into your `setTeam` function is a string, so your comparison fails as you're trying to compare a string with an object. You can change your comparison to extract the `team` property from your object:

```
gameState.selected_teams[0]?.team != team
```

The `?` ensures that a value exists at index `0` in your array before using `.team` on it (otherwise you would get an error if it's `undefined`).

You can adapt this code to handle more than one object by using `.every()` to check that all objects in selected_team's aren't equal to the one you're adding:

```
if(gameState.selected_teams.length < 2 && gameState.selected_teams.every(obj => obj.team != team)
```

---

If you don't need to pass an object `{team: team}` (as an object with one property doesn't add much value), then you can simply push your `team` string into your selected teams, and use `.includes()` to check if the team you're adding already exists in the array:

```
selected_teams: [
  ...prevState.selected_teams, team
]
```

you can then update your condition to use `.includes()`:

```js
if(gameState.selected_teams.length < 2 && !gameState.selected_teams.includes(team))
```